# Posting back a list, The list is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm trying to post back an editable list in MVC however with my original view the list always returns null. I have a view model list and all the results get displayed in a form with a few that are editable. I did some goolging and found this http://forums.asp.net/t/1848323.aspx?MVC+Model+List+Httppost+always+null that is pretty much the same question. I tried implanting this with an `IList` but I'm still posting back a null list. Any ideas why or how to post back the list? Any questions or if more info/code is needed let me know. Thank you.

**View Original using IEnumerable**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { name = "frm", id = "frm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)    

    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <!--  Partial View Form -->
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/Partial/PartialEdit.cshtml", item)  
    <hr />
}


<div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Save" />
    </p>
</div>
```

}

**View Current for using an IList**

```
@model IList<NavLiveWebInterface.ViewModel.Proc_Item_SKUViewModel>
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <!--  Partial View Form -->
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/Partial/PartialEdit.cshtml", Model[i])  
    <hr />
}
```

**Partial View**

```
@model NavLiveWebInterface.ViewModel.Proc_Item_SKUViewModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Item_SKU)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Item_SKU,new { disabled="disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Master_SKU)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Master_SKU,new { disabled="disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Attribute_Code)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Attribute_Code,new { disabled="disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name,new { disabled="disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sample_Quantity)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Sample_Quantity)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="editor-label paddinglabel">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Usage)
        </div>
        <div class="paddingdropdown">
            <div class="editor-field dropdown">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Usage, Model.TrueFalse)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Usage)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="editor-label paddinglabel">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Filterable)
        </div>
        <div class="paddingdropdown">
            <div class="editor-field dropdown">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Filterable, Model.TrueFalse)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Filterable)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="editor-label paddinglabel">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Display)
        </div>
        <div class="paddingdropdown">
            <div class="editor-field dropdown">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Display, Model.TrueFalse)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Display)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description,new { disabled="disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller HTTP POST**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(IList<Proc_Item_SKUViewModel> vmList)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //updates the items
            _repository.updateItems(vmList);                

            return RedirectToAction("../Home/Index");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
    }
    return View(vmList);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still think the problem is the fact that your inputs are not indexed. Just like the answer @ http://forums.asp.net/t/1848323.aspx?MVC+Model+List+Httppost+always+null

You are using Model[i] to render the partial, but inside the partial the input fields will conflict with the input fields from the other items in the Model. Just look at the produced HTML, you can see that the input fields will have duplicate names and or IDs (and they also have no indexer)

I don't think this will work with PartialView the way things are currently set up. Easiest way is to lose the PartialView and just put the HTML in the loop and use the following structure:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].Master_SKU)
}
```

Pay attention to the **indexer** @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model **[i]** ).Master_SKU